# How to install SSL certificate on Amazon ELB?

Tags: ssl, web, amazon-ec2, server, amazon-elb

So I've been trying to get this SSL certificate installed on an Amazon NodeJS EC2/EJB server I have set up, but for the life of me I can't get it working.

Basically, I have a Godaddy domain and SSL certificate, and I setup a subdomain (let's say admin.example.com) on the Goddaddy site to point to the amazon server through Amazon's Route 53 tool. So, nameservers and redirecting is all fine, but my site doesn't show that it's secure.

If I go to admin.example.com, the site says 'Not Secure' with no warning, and I can't connect to https://admin.example.com. If I instead go to the beanstalk url (https://example.beanstalk.com), the site says 'Not Secure' with a red mark. I ran the beanstalk url through an HTTPS checking tool, and it said the only problem was the url's mismatching (since the SSL is registered for admin.example.com, not the beanstalk url).

Do I need to register a certificate for the beanstalk url instead? How can I setup this subdomain so it will use HTTPS? I'm pretty new to this, but I don't believe it should be this difficult to setup. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question to make sure it will is, is the Certificate a wildcard certificate? If it is not it will, most likely, only work for the root domain and admin.example.com. Are you using an ELB with the Beanstalk deployment or just one instance?

How to request a wildcard from ACM ( This will work for Load Balancers and Cloudfront)

> You can also use an asterisk (*) as a wildcard in the leftmost
>   position to protect several site names in the same domain. For
>   example, *.example.com protects corp.example.com, and
>   images.example.com. The wildcard name will appear in the Subject field
>   and the Subject Alternative Name extension of the ACM Certificate.
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request.html

[How to upload a certificate to IAM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-ssl-upload.html)

```
$ aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name elastic-beanstalk-x509 --certificate-body file://https-cert.crt --private-key file://private-key.pem
{
    "ServerCertificateMetadata": {
        "ServerCertificateId": "AS5YBEIONO2Q7CAIHKNGC",
        "ServerCertificateName": "elastic-beanstalk-x509",
        "Expiration": "2017-01-31T23:06:22Z",
        "Path": "/",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:server-certificate/elastic-beanstalk-x509",
        "UploadDate": "2016-02-01T23:10:34.167Z"
    }
}
```

> Make note of the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) for your certificate. You
>   will use it when you update your load balancer configuration settings
>   to use HTTPS.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html